# How can I find out where a CA file is set in Mac OS?

Tags: macos, curl

Problem: Can't find where CAfile is configured for curl

When I try and run curl and other commands that use curl behind the scenes whether via php (composer) or curl directly, I get an error for self-signed certificates because my company injects their own cert.

An example:
`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`

and get the output:
`fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/': error setting certificate verify locations:  CAfile: /Users/kdoyle/Downloads/SEI-PKI-2.crt CApath: none`

I cannot find where that setting is configured. I've checked the following locations:
`~/.curlrc` -> doesn't exist

Comment: I've also checked the following locations and there is no CA file configured in any of them.

`~/.zshrc`, `~/.zprofile` and `~/.bashrc` doesn't exist.

Comment: Have you checked for default configuration file? https://everything.curl.dev/cmdline/configfile#default-config-file